# Unable to start riak

Tags: server

I am trying to install riak on Ubuntu Server 12.04 LTS 64-bit on virtual box. I am following [this guide](http://developer.muchdifferent.com/unitypark/uGameDB/HowtoRiakOnVirtualBox). I've completed all the steps mentioned in it. But when I do `riak start`, it says

> unable to access /var/run/riak , permission denied run script as root

So I did `sudo riak start` and then I got a warning

> warning ulimit -n is 1024. 4096 is minimum

and after that the node doesn't start. When I check by typing `riak-admin test` it says

> Node is not running!!

I am new to Ubuntu(actually just using it for the first time, just to install riak). Any idea how can I start riak? I've already installed openssl0.9.8 and erlang.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently I put wrong ip address in one of the place. Checked it again and the issue got fixed.